# A more formal English expression for K-12 (in the US)?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

This is US-specific.

I had mistakenly believed that *grade school* meant K-12. Turns out it refers only to elementary school. Is there a more formal (but fairly succinct) English expression for K-12?

Comment: I think "K-12" itself is quite formal.

Comment: [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%E2%80%9312) I assume provides a correct description of what this means. I had never come across it before. It is not used in the UK, perhaps for the simple reason that there are very few schools that provide for children from age 5 to 18. If there were I have no idea what they would be called. Our system is - under 5 - *nursery*; 5-10 *primary*, 11-16 - *secondary*; 17-18 - *6th form*. Above that all education is described as *tertiary*.

Comment: *Secondary School* and *primary school* are more specific versions of what you're looking for. I'm not sure if there is a single word to describe what you're looking for. You might be able to say *pre-tertiary school*

Comment: Secondary and pre-tertiary are not US terms.  The basic education system in the US (government-provided) is K-12 but 9-12 are considered "high school" and I've never seen a school that provides for children 5-18.  Kindergarten - 5th (sometime 6th grade) is Primary, 6 (or 7) through 8 is usually considered junior high.

Comment: @KristinaLopez there are secondary schools in Michigan which are grades 9 - 12.

Comment: @WS2 There are very few schools in the US that have all those grade levels as well. *K-12* simply refers to all elementary and secondary education, as there is a much sharper distinction between *K-12* and with *higher education* (*postsecondary education*, i.e. *college and grad school*) than between elementary and secondary schools. As for the breakdown, it varies by state and district. Around DC, schools are K-5, 6-8, 9-12; elsewhere they are K-6, 7-8, 9-12; or K-4, 5-8, 9-12; or K-6, 7-9, 10-12; etc.

Comment: In the US,  K-12 (pronounced variously -- Kay-twelve, Kay-to-twelve, Kay-thru-twelve), and ELHI (or ElHi) are in use.  They make it into serious publications, but they may not be formal enough for you.

Comment: @GEdgar: It could well be that "K-12" has now become a formal term. This would however be quite interesting, given that to my knowledge, there is no other term in US English in which a string of letter(s), punctuation mark(s), and number(s) would be considered a formal term.

Comment: @Othya, you're right... I just went through the list of schools in Michigan and there are a few actually named "Secondary School".  The vast majority are named "XYZ High School".

Comment: @KennyLJ Just what do you mean by "formal"? Government and science and academia are thoroughly permeated by strings of letters, punctuation, and numbers. Just ask any [O-7](http://www.defense.gov/about/insignias/officers.aspx).

Comment: It's not uncommon to see a school *district* categorize its education program as providing for K-12.

Comment: I asked a similar question a while back: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/235561/what-to-call-primary-school-high-school-but-not-college

Comment: Ask a K-9 drug sniffing patrol (the symbol is printed in official vehicle livery in more than one instance) part of the 5-O (pronounced five oh, but that's slang) about combining letter, number and dash.  Also don't forget your vitamins.

Comment: You could describe it as pre-post-secondary education. ;-)